# Finding the speed at which a certain number increases

Tags: php

I have a file named "progress.txt", and it contains a constantly changing integer (always rising). Is there a way to use PHP to determine the speed at which it rises per second?

Comment: I assume that the file in a location that your php server can access. What exactly do you want to do with the information? Refresh the screen with the rate of increase? How often do you want to update this?

Comment: I was thinking multiple times a second with JavaScript, so I cannot have measuring the difference in the number every second. I need something that could provide next-to-instant calculations.

Comment: wait - do you want to use php or javascript? You do realize that one is server side and the other is client side, right? Now I'm confused...

Comment: I'm making a file called ips.php, which does the calculation, then loading it onto the screen and refreshing it multiple times a second with JavaScript.

Comment: Realize that the php code needs to read the file more than once in order to compute the difference (and thus the rate of change). This means that it needs to run until the value changes at least once, preferably more than once (because you don't know how long the file had a certain value in it when you first read it). How often does the file change?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you would find the following php code useful:

```
<?php

$fileName="progress.txt";
$delay = 100;
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);

$first = file_get_contents($fileName);
$second = $first;
while($second == $first || strlen($second)==0) {
  $second = file_get_contents($fileName);
  $t1 = microtime(TRUE);
  usleep($delay);
}
$third = $second;
while($third == $second || strlen($third)==0) {
  $third = file_get_contents($fileName);
  $t2 = microtime(TRUE);
  usleep($delay);
}

echo "rate of change is ".($third - $second) / ($t2 - $t1)." per second\n";
?>
```

This reads the file (skipping any warnings) until it has read three different values. The first value it ignores (you don't know how long it's been there), then it finds the time of the second and the third change to the file. It reports the difference between these values divided by the time it took for the change to occur.

Note - depending on the time resolution you can tolerate you will want to put a (small) delay in each of the `while` loops to prevent a complete lockup of the thread in which the code is running. That is the purpose of the `usleep` call. You might want to experiment with the `$delay` parameter to see what works best for you.

Comment: You spent more effort than the questioner over the problem.

Comment: @EdHeal - true... But sometimes I just need a small hacking challenge.